# How to catch a JavaScript error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have a lot of JavaScript code that get's executed on a website. If every plugin works, everything is fine. But when only one JavaScript error occurs, all other code fails, too.

I am concatenating all JavaScript code to one file. This is currently a must, so a change here is not possible.

What's the general way of preventing (vendor) code not fail everything else?

**EDIT:**

To simplify my question: What's the best way of handling big JavaScript error from vendor code?

Comment: You really do need to fix the problem properly, but here's a link to what you're asking for... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: U can check console Debugger Using F12 Sources tab.. Enable a Debugger, Here u can find which javascript file of which line u gets error. We can find easily..

Comment: @Archer That's not applicable to the question being asked here. Did you read it?

Comment: @JLRishe wrapping offending 3rd party code in try/catch *will* answer the OP's question.  Not sure why you think it won't.

Comment: @Archer OP is concatenating several JS files together into one and is worrying that a failure in one of them would cause all of the others to fail to load. How would a try-catch help with that? Are you suggesting that OP wrap the entire contents of each file in a try-catch?

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting exactly that.  Like I said originally, I think he should fix the problem correctly, but he says *"This is currently a must, so a change here is not possible."*  I wouldn't even consider what I'm suggesting, personally, but it suits his requirements.  Also note, I'm not posting this as an answer.  I wouldn't be that cruel to any future readers!

Answer (score 0):

Your error handling should be as simple as the following example:

```
try{
 var x = functionThatDoesNotExist();
}
catch(error){
    console.log('An error occured');
  console.log(error);
}
```

You should try and break down your javascript files according to the templates that contain your HTML markup, and simply when an error occurs do not render that template.

You can read more on Try/Catch [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).